# AWS IoT MQTT setup quota and throttling per client

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Is there any way setup quota and throttling such as ApiGateway for AWS IoT? I want to avoid a situation where clients will send a huge number of messages to MQTT, for example, I would like to limit messages sent to MQTT to 1 message per second.

Similar question with body validation (structure and size).

Of course, I can use lambda and ApiGateway and then send message to MQTT, but it seems to me that this is an overhead

Perhaps there are some best practices?

Answer (score 0):

For the throttling part, I have used [API Gateway with api key and usage plan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html). You don't need a lambda, api gateway can be integrated with AWS IoT service directly for publish.
The structure of the request can be validated using [request validation in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html).

Now, if you also need to check the content length, then you would need to have a lambda to validate it. Or you can use [AWS WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-web-acl-size-conditions.html).